# Tabela oncick no <td> transformar o texto em um input text e quando clicar fora alterar o valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Olá, eu queria saber como eu posso fazer para alterar o valor de um td da seguinte maneira:

```
<table class="tb">
<tr><td>Valor 1</td><td>Valor 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Valor 3</td><td>Valor 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Se possível eu queria a solução em Jquery, sem precisar colocar IDs em todos TD, além disto seria melhor se não tivesse nenhum input invisível (No caso seria melhor um javascript que funcione em todo tipo de tabela).

A pessoa clica, transforma em um textfield, digita o valor alterado e depois que clica fora altera o valor.

O que eu quero seria apenas fazer funcionar esta funcionalidade básica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer isso [com `contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable). Desse modo permites que o HTML seja alterado e podes re-ler o html para saber o conteudo novo.

```html
<table class="tb" contenteditable="true">
    <tr>
        <td>Valor 1</td>
        <td>Valor 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor 3</td>
        <td>Valor 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eppLwzme/